# How to use the git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM?

Tags: ruby, git, hook, pre-commit-hook

I trying to write the `pre-receive` hook to check the committing file. I tried to use the git command `git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM` to get the file committed file list. But I get exception

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

Dir[git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM].any? do |f|
 %w|.txt .pdf .dll|.include?(File.extname(f))
   puts "Your commit have exe or dll file. Kindly remove the file an$
 exit 0
```

end

But I get syntax error on 3rd line

> syntax error, unexpected unary-, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' (SyntaxError)

As a `ruby` script beginner, I can not predict why this happening. I need a hand to fix the issue.

Update As per [elpiekay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6330106/elpiekay) guidence.

```
for line in ARGF.readlines;arr=line.split();oldvalue=arr[0];newvalue=arr‌​[1];refname=arr[2];

Dir[git diff $oldvalue $newvalue --name-only --diff-filter=ACM].any? do |f|
 %w|.txt .pdf .dll|.include?(File.extname(f))
   puts "Your commit have exe or dll file. Kindly remove the file and try again"
 exit 1
 end
exit 0
end
```

But Now also I facing the same error in `Dir[git diff $oldvalue $newvalue --name-only --diff-filter=ACM].any? do |f|` line.

Comment: `git diff --cached` can't work in a `pre-receive` hook. You need to get the old value and the new value of the updated ref from the standard input, and then get the changed files between the two values via `git diff $oldvalue $newvalue --name-only --diff-filter=ACM`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thank you for your valuable information, You directed me right way, How could I get the  `$oldvalue $newvalue `?  Any suggestion?

Comment: `for line in ARGF.readlines;arr=line.split();oldvalue=arr[0];newvalue=arr[1];refname=arr[2];#here do something;end`. Put this snippet in the `pre-receive` hook.

Comment: @ElpieKay Once again Thank you for your hand, I updated the question as per your answer, But I facing the same issue here too!  Could you please lemme know the mistake I did?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Ruby, so I can just do it in `bash`.

```
#!/bin/bash

z40=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

while read oldvalue newvalue refname
do
    if [ "$newvalue" == "$z40" ];then
        #Trying to delete the ref, do something here
        :
    else
        if [ "$oldvalue" == "$z40" ];then
            #Trying to create a new ref, do something here
            :
        else
            git diff $oldvalue $newvalue --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | if grep -e ".txt" -e ".pdf" -e ".dll";then
                echo "Your commit has txt, pdf or dll file(s). Kindly remove the file(s) and try again"
                exit 1
            fi
        fi
    fi
done
```